# SQL Count in View as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view, count

I'm trying to get the result of a COUNT as a column in my view.
Please see the below query for a demo of the kind of thing I want (this is just for demo purposes)

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ord WHERE ord.ProductID = prod.ProductID) AS TotalNumberOfOrders

FROM tblProducts prod
LEFT JOIN tblOrders ord ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
```

This obviously isn't working... but I was wondering what the correct way of doing this would be?

I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query would actually work if you removed the join - it's not actually used, and it will cause the ord table within the [inner select subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252(SQL.80).aspx) to conflict with the ord table that you've joined to:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ord WHERE ord.ProductID = prod.ProductID) AS TotalNumberOfOrders
FROM tblProducts prod
```

Alternatively, you can actually make use of the joined table in conjunction with [`Group By`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    COUNT(ord.ProductID) AS TotalNumberOfOrders
FROM tblProducts prod
LEFT JOIN tblOrders ord ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
GROUP BY
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    ProductID,  
    Name,  
    Description,  
    Price,  
count(*) as totalnumberoforders
FROM tblProducts prod 
LEFT JOIN tblOrders ord ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID 
group by
    ProductID,  
    Name,  
    Description,  
    Price
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the products that have been ordered, you could simply substitute the LEFT OUTER JOIN operation with an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    prod.ProductID, 
    prod.Name, 
    prod.Description, 
    prod. Price, 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalNumberOfOrders
FROM tblProducts prod
INNER JOIN tblOrders ord ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    COUNT(ord.ProductId) AS TotalNumberOfOrders
FROM tblProducts prod
LEFT JOIN tblOrders ord
 ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
GROUP BY
    ProductID, 
    Name, 
    Description, 
    Price
```

The "COUNT(ord.ProductId)" clause ensures that if no orders are found, TotalNumberOfOrders will be equal to zero.

[Later edit: I forgot the GROUP BY clause. Doh!]